# WCF - C# service should send results continuously

Tags: c#, wcf, streaming

Since it's a long question, cliff notes come first.

**Cliff notes:**
***One client sends input to several services and they keep on working and sending results until the client tells them to stop or they have reached a pre-set maximum number of results.***

Do you know how one should go about implementing this, or do you have a C#-example for sth. like this? Is WCF & streaming the right toolset for this ? (Consider that results are custom objects, so it's not exactly the same as streaming a file)

**More Detailed Problem Definition:**

*Situation:*

- I have full control over the code of the client and the services (iow not dependent on closed 3rd party stuff)
- everything is in C#
- We have one client who wants to get one task done and has several equal independent services for that.
  (equal = equal service-software, the hardware on which each service runs can vary -> service-speeds can vary)
- One task consists of "1000 pieces of work" which are all independent from one another.
- Within one task all of the 1000 pieces of work are based upon the same piece of input data.

I mention solutions A+B since I think they help explaining the problem:

**Solution (A) - The slow non-parallel way:**
1. Client sends input to one service.
2. Service initializes based upon the input.
3. Service processes all 1000 pieces of work
  (results get added up(super fast btw) so the result of 1000 pieces of work has the same size as the result of one)
4. Service sends result to the client.
5. Client receives result and is happy

**Solution (B) - Parallel faster way:**
Let's say ten services, so we evenly split it up and each should process 100.

The problem is some services may be much faster than others so giving each the same number(100) is slower than 
necessary.
Furthermore we can't split up according to an a priori speed-test since the speed of one service can change and 
some might even go down during processing, these are the reasons why I think the following would be best for my purpose.

**Solution (C) - The way I would like to implement it:**
Client sends out the same request to all services. (same request still implies that the task get's processed in parallel, parallelization is super easy for my problem 1000 pieces of work are so independent that doing 1000 times the "first" piece of work means we are done)

A service keeps working and sending results until it is told to stop or has processed 1000 pieces of work.
One result gets sent for 10 pieces of work done.
**This means all services work parallel on the task and when the client has gotten a sum of 1000 results from all service replies combined it will send the stop signal.**
That means normally no single service should reach 1000, but with having 1000 we have covered the situation where there is only one service and we have a fail-safe to avoid infinite loops if the stop signal gets lost. (client neither needs to wait nor to be absolutely sure that the stop signal has reached a service)

Throwing away additional results beyond our goal of 1000 is fine.

(The alternative of instead making follow-up requests to services that have responded faster than others would come
 with the overhead of wasted time due to messages going back and forth and additional initializations. 
 (Add. inits could be avoided but it would be complicated and you still have the other overhead))

***I basically have solutions/would know how to implement A+B but I have no clue how I would go about realizing (C).
How do you implement a client/service-architecture in C# where the service keeps sending results and doesn't just return one object/value? (Results are custom objects, btw)
Does someone know about C#-example-code where sth. like that is implemented? Would streaming be the right way?***

I've found the ["writing a custom stream"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx)-example but it seems like it's a pretty long way from there to what I want. (As a WCF-noob I can easily be wrong on that though.)

Comment: I still don't understand how the service knows which "piece of work it should do". Does it mean that a task actually is do something 1000 times? Because that is the only scenario where I can imagine that solution C make sense.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka,
Yes think of Monte Carlo simulations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Streaming in the WCF doesn't work in the way that you will open a stream, return the stream to the client and service will still generate results to the stream. If you want to work this way you must go deeper and use sockets directly. In WCF the stream must be written prior to returning it from the operation (I tried to write to returned stream from other thread but it didn't work). Streaming in WCF is only for data transport.

I don't like any of your solution. I would try:

1. Variant of B. But tasks will not be divided equally upfront. If you have 10 services and 1000 tasks you will send first 10 tasks (each to one service) only only after the service returns the result it will get another task. If tasks can be completed within reasonable time you will need only multiple async calls to services and wait for responses. If any service will not be able to complete task within defined timeout you will send the task to another service. If tasks can be completed fast you can send small batches instead of single task. If task completion takes long you will need duplex communication.
2. Use Transactional Message queue - MSMQ. You client will generate 1000 messages to "producer queue" and services will take these messages one by one and process them. They will send results as message to another "consumer queue" where client will take results and process them (each result must have correlation to the task). Transactional queue will ensure that each task can be processed only by single service but if service fails or timeout of the transaction will occur the task will be available for processing in another service. MSMQ also offers some additional features like queue for faulty tasks etc. This is little bit advanced scenario. The main problem of this scenario can be limitation in size of messages (max. 4MB per message).

Edit:

Ok because of your clarification it looks like you need to send the same task to multiple services and task will just trigger series of the same computation on the same data. You can achieve it in this way:

- Build a duplex service using Net.tcp binding
- Service will implement service contract which will have operations to start computation and to stop computation (you can use `IsInitiating` and `IsTerminating` properties of `OperationContract`)
- Service will do computation in separate thread started in start operation
- Stop operation will abort computation thread
- Client will implement callback contract to receive results from the service
- Service will call the client callback when the processing thread has result (or multiple results) to send back

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) is an example of using duplex services with `WsDualHttpBinding` - don't use this binding in your scenario because it is much more complicated if you want to have single client to communicate with multiple same services over duplex HTTP.

Comment: First of all thanks for taking the time to answer.  
_> "I don't like any of your solution"_
A+B are just for explanation, if I would be happy with them I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place since I have them already. Since I do want to implement solution C it would be helpful if you could let me know what you don't like about C.

Comment: What I don't like about solution C? Sending same data to all services and wait which will complete the processing first is not a solution if you can divide processing among them.

Comment: @suggestion 1:
I mentioned that I want to avoid "overhead of wasted time due to messages going back and forth" and in the variant of B the server would wait to get the same task reassigned. This includes three things I explicitly don't want: (1) more messages going back and forth than necessary. (2)service waits to get (3)reassigned the same task.  @(2)I don't want a service to wait and @(3)I don't want the same task to get reassigned. (initialization overhead)

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka
Ok thanks, that's a misunderstanding of C I'm going to edit for clarification

Comment: So why do you use multiple services in the first place? As I read your description I completely don't understand what you are trying to do because things which you don't want seems pretty strange - that is really just about race. Send the request to all services and wait for the first complete result. Nothing else is needed.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka 
I have clarified the description of C. (the processing is divided amongst them sending the same data is fine in my case.)

Comment: Thanks implementing the suggestions from the "Edit:"-section worked.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe as Solution (C) sounds like a good use for Asynchronous WCF.  Some of these might help...

[Synchronous and Asynchronous Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx)
[Asynchronous Programming Design Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx)
[How to: Call WCF Service Operations Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx)